# Behavior of localized push notifications using FCM

Tags: android, ios, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are using localized notifications through FCM and are wondering how android and ios is working in certain situations:

1. when we send localized notification with title_loc_key and body_loc_key and there is no key for title nor body in the application, is the system going to show something to user?
2. what is the behavior of sending notification to firebase with loc_key and standard title and body parameters? Is the system going to use primarily the localized ones and if they are not available, they fallback to the standart ones?

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So experimentally I have found out that if you send in one notification loc_keys and normal title and body, if the application has the translation, it shows the localized notification and if not, it fallbacks to the normal title and body properties.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How did you do that? Can you share your payload? Here they seem to say the opposite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72964688/behavior-of-localized-push-notifications-using-fcm

Comment: I am currently experiencing the opposite of this behavior on Android (12). When both "loc" strings are set and available in the app these get overruled when the general "title" and "body" attributes are set in the message payload. If you leave out these general attributes the notification defaults to the localized strings in the app. Very frustrating choice ...

Comment: @Raj weird thing, everything is working fine in our application theese days. The bad thing is that there is no documantation for that from Google.